# Codeigniter css not loading/Google API PHP client not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

When I moved my Google API php client code to hosting server, it stopped working. While debugging I found that its not able to get `@_GET['code']`.

I found same issue on SO as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274164/not-able-to-get-getcode-for-google-oauth-on-codeigniter)

But when I changed my config.php `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`, all the css files stop loading on the page. So I dont know changing this config value will resolve my first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CSS , did you use

```
<?php echo base_ur('css/style.css'); ?> // ci_app_path/css/style.css
```

It is  a good practise . You can set base_url() in application/config/config.php.

**For GET**

Can you try with $_POST ?